# What is the right way to alter sqlite3 database?

Tags: database, sqlite

I've been using sqlite3 in my projects for a while now. And every time I had to make changes to the tables, (for example, add a new column with a foreign key reference) I do the following.

1. Copy the database and create an SQL export `INSERT` queries from that.
2. Build the database anew with the new schema.
3. Then modify the INSERT queries to accommodate new columns and then import it into the new database.

I do this with SQLitebrowser.

Am I doing this wrong? What is the right programmatic way to do this?

**Additional information:** I am not using any ORMs.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this way to do it:

```
To do this, you can create a new table (with the new column definition), populate the table with the data from the old table, then once complete, delete the old table and rename the new one to reflect the original name.

Create the New Table
First, create the new table (notice ReleaseDate instead of Year).

CREATE TABLE Albums(
  AlbumId     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  AlbumName   TEXT NOT NULL,
  ReleaseDate TEXT,
  ArtistId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(ArtistId) REFERENCES Artists(ArtistId)
);
So we now have the following tables in our database:

sqlite> .tables
Albums   Albums1  Artists
Insert Data
Then insert the data from the old table.

Use an INSERT statement that selects data from the old table and inserts it into the new table. Like this:

INSERT INTO Albums (AlbumId, AlbumName, ReleaseDate, ArtistId)
SELECT AlbumId, AlbumName, Year, ArtistId
FROM Albums1;
Verify that the data was inserted into the new table:

sqlite> SELECT * FROM Albums;
AlbumId   AlbumName                        ReleaseDate  ArtistId  
--------  -------------------------------  -----------  ----------
1         Killers                          1981         7         
2         Powerslave                       1984         7         
3         Surfing with the Alien           1987         1         
4         Heavy as a Really Heavy Thing    1995         11        
5         Yummy Yummy                      1994         17        
6         Out of the Loop                  2007         6         
7         Suck on This                     1989         13        
8         Pork Soda                        1993         13        
9         Sailing the Seas of Cheese       1991         13        
10        Flying in a Blue Dream           1989         1         
11        Black Swans and Wormhole Wizard  2010         1         
12        Somewhere in Time                1986         7         

Drop the Old Table
```

Maybe this is nearly the same that you do!